# Unable to access class variables in function

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am trying to create a database with encryption. I am making a php script that inserts data into a database.

I am unable to retrieve any of my class variables (specifically `$this->decryptionKey`)

```
class DBHandler {
public $decryptionKey = "hi";
public $dbhost;
public $dbuser;
public $dbpass;

function DBHandler(){
    echo $this->decryptionKey;
    $this->decryptionKey = "PASSWORD";
    echo $this->decryptionKey;
    $this->dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
    $this->dbuser = 'root';
    $this->dbpass = 'password';
}

function insertStudent($id, $fName, $lName, $email, $phone){
    //connect to database
    echo $this->decryptionKey;
    echo "hello";
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'password', "", 3306);




    echo "world";

    //define sql code
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Checkout_System`.`STUDENT` " . "(`STUDENT_ID`, `STUDENT_FNAME`, `STUDENT_LNAME`, `STUDENT_EMAIL`, ". "`STUDENT_PHONE`, `STUDENT_OFFENSE_COUNT`) " . "VALUES (" . $id . ", AES_ENCRYPT(\'" . $fName . "\', \'" . $this->decryptionKey. "\'), AES_ENCRYPT(\'" . $lName . "\', \'" . $this->decryptionKey . "\'), AES_ENCRYPT(\'" . $email . "\', \'" . $this->decryptionKey . "\'), AES_ENCRYPT(\'" . $phone . "\', \'" . $this->decryptionKey. "\'), 0);";

    echo "hello!!!!!";

    //execute query
    $retval = mysqli_query($link, $sql);


    //check success
    if(!$retval){
        die('Failure:' . mysql_error());
        echo "<script>console.log(\"failure\")</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>console.log(\"failure\")</script>";
    }


}

function template($id, $fName, $lName, $email, $phone){
    //connect to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);

    //define sql code
    $sql = "";

    //execute query
    $retval = mysqli_query($link, $sql);


    //check success
    if(!$retval){
        die('Failure:' . mysql_error());
        print("failure");
    }
    else{
        print("SUCCESS!");
    }
}   
  }
```

the output of that is the following:

`hiPASSWORD`

I have no idea why I am able to access the variable in the one "constructor" function, but not the other one. I tried making a getter for the variable, but that failed too. I am unable to use debugging features of NetBeans because it does not want to work with the existing NetBeans Debugging Tools.

Comment: Perhaps an error occurs while you are trying to establish a mysql connection, so the scripts stop working at this line: `$link = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'password', "", 3306);`

Check if you have correct config. You pass an empty string as database name `""`. Try to specify a database name like this:

`$link = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'password', "databaseName", 3306);`

Comment: @Battle_mage I was unable to get it to work when it is the first line in the function. I was originally trying to use the `$dbhost` and other variables for the parameters of mysql_connect.